# How to export the api call results to a csv with the values of single response in one row?

Tags: json, reactjs, export-to-csv

My api response looks like below

```
    [
    {
        "What time is it?": [
            "option_2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "When will we go home?": [
            "option_1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "When is your birthday?": [
            "2050"
        ]
    },
    {
        "How much do you sleep?": [
            "Ajajajsjiskskskskdkdj"
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "What time is it?": [
            "option_2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "When will we go home?": [
            "option_1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "When is your birthday?": [
            "10181"
        ]
    },
    {
        "How much do you sleep?": [
            "Ajskossooskdncpqpqpwkdkdkskkskskksksksksks"
        ]
    }
]
```

Now in react, I want to export the results to a csv. I can do it by export-to-csv but the formatting is the issue here. I want the values of each question  of a single response in one row under their labels(questions). So if I have two response like above I want to have export it in two rows, not 8 as there are 8 total questions.
Here is how I want it to get exported.[image: export-data]

I have tried so far like this but no luck.

this is my export data function

```
exp =()=>{

  const raw = []
  console.log(this.state.data[0].sbm_id)
    axios.get(`/dashboard/${this.props.proj_id}/whole_sub/`)
        .then(res=>{
          // console.log('1')
          // console.log(res.data[0][0])
          // console.log('2')
          for (let i =0;i<this.state.data.length;i++){
            for(let j = 0;j<res.data[0].length;j++){
         // let sub=[]
          //res.data[i][j].ID = this.state.data[i].sbm_id
            raw.push(res.data[i][j])
            }
          }
        }
        )

          let curr = this.state
          curr.exp = raw
          this.setState({exp:curr.exp})



        }
```

Here is my export function

```
rawExport=()=>{


  const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(optionsExp);

  csvExporter.generateCsv(this.state.exp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is to flatten the initial nested array to get a homogeneously shaped array, then you keep on reducing it further.

```js
const data = [
 [
  {
   "What time is it?": [
    "option_2"
   ]
  },
  {
   "When will we go home?": [
    "option_1"
   ]
  },
  {
   "When is your birthday?": [
    "2050"
   ]
  },
  {
   "How much do you sleep?": [
    "Ajajajsjiskskskskdkdj"
   ]
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "What time is it?": [
    "option_2"
   ]
  },
  {
   "When will we go home?": [
    "option_1"
   ]
  },
  {
   "When is your birthday?": [
    "10181"
   ]
  },
  {
   "How much do you sleep?": [
    "Ajskossooskdncpqpqpwkdkdkskkskskksksksksks"
   ]
  }
 ]
];

const flattenArray = (arr) => [].concat.apply([], arr);

// Flatten the initial array
const flattenedArray = flattenArray(data);

// Keep on reducing the flattened array into an object
var res = flattenedArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 const [key, val] = flattenArray(Object.entries(curr));
 if (!acc[key]) {
  acc[key] = [].concat(val);
 } else {
  val.forEach(x => {
   if (!acc[key].includes(x)) {
    acc[key].push(x);
   }
  });
 }
 return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```